# Converting polygon to line with neighbor info using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, adjacency

Is it possible to create lines from polygons with information about neighbors in QGIS?

I would like to do this for land plots. There is a tool in ArcMap that works like a charm, but I do not see anything like that in QGIS. For clarification, I mean to generate plot boundaries with information on which plots the given boundary applies to.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit and maybe join a screenshot to have a better idea of what you expect ?

Comment: The tool `Polygons to lines` will convert the plots to lines which retain their attribute values. So first you need to do some kind of spatial join to get all the attributes you want into each polygon.

Comment: Or maybe add a field using the aggregate functions in the field calculator. It depends on which information you want from the adjacent plots, and how you want it presented. Eg, you could combine all the IDs from adjacent plots into a comma-separated field called "Adjacent_Plot_IDs." If you explain exactly what information you want in the output, I can help with the right expression to use.

Comment: Imagine a square A to which sides adjoin the next squares B, C, D, E. I need a tool that will create a border (lines) AB, AC, AD, AE containing complete information about neighboring polygons. As I said the tool in ArcMap can do it without a problem, giving information about the polygons ID on both sides of the border, I can attach the rest of the information from the source file.